# two arraylist merge with the same father class in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, merge

I have a question. Right now, I have three classes.

```
public C(){}

public A extends C {}

public B extends C {}
```

What I want to do is to create two arraylist:

```
ArrayList<A> list_A;
ArrayList<B> list_B;
```

Finally, I want to merge this two arraylists with the same father class.

I check the forum: `list_A.addAll(list_B)` is used with the same class object.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge them in a container of the super type :

```
ArrayList<C> list_C = new ArrayList<C>();
list_C.addAll(list_A);
list_C.addAll(list_B);
```